# Why is an image defined within HTML not loading?

Tags: html, angular, image

I'm putting image in `<img>` HTML tag, but the browser refuses to load it.

I've already tried:

```
 <img src="C:/Users/פניני/TRIP4U/נוכחי/TRIP4U/src/images/map-reka.png" usemap="#tiulim-map" border="0" alt="">

        <img src="file:///C:/Users/פניני/TRIP4U/נוכחי/TRIP4U/src/images/map-reka.png" usemap="#tiulim-map" border="0" alt="">

          <img src="/src/images/map-reka.png" usemap="#tiulim-map" border="0" alt="">

            <img src="assets/map-reka.png" usemap="#tiulim-map" border="0" alt="">
```

I expect the image to show on screen, but the browser gives me an error as:

> Not allowed to load local resource

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide your project directory structure please? Including what file you’re loading the image into.

Comment: The message is clear about what happens. You try to Access a file on the file System, not from the project context. Drop the image into the Assets Folder and access it like this--> src='assets/{path to image}'. The assets folder is usually located in the root path of your project.